# scrapy has response status 400 , but browser response is ok?

Tags: python, scrapy, polipo

I have this strange situation,

I have a link that works on all borwsers that I currently have (`chrome,IE,firefox`),
I tried to crawl the page using `scrapy` in `python`. however I get `response.status == 400`,
I am using `tor + polipo` to crawl anonymously

`response.body` is :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html><head>
<title>Proxy error: 400 Couldn't parse URL.</title>
</head><body>
<h1>400 Couldn't parse URL</h1>
<p>The following error occurred while trying to access <strong>https://exmpale.com/blah</strong>:<br><br>
<strong>400 Couldn't parse URL</strong></p>
<hr>Generated Thu, 11 Dec 2014 13:55:38 UTC by Polipo on <em>localhost:8123</em>.
</body></html>
```

I'm just wondering why that should be, could it be that browser can get results but not `scrapy`?

Comment: Could you show the code you are using here?

Comment: Perhaps the server is blocking scrapy? Try changing the user agent.

Comment: @selllikesybok well scrapy project is quite big to fit it here, is there any specific part I should show?

Comment: @RamchandraApte  so far I tried over 10 different agents, I keep trying to see if I get anything

Comment: @nafas The website may be blocking because of Tor.

Comment: @nafas for starters, the line where response is assigned a value?

Comment: @RamchandraApte well it works for some of the pages, but not all

Comment: @selllikesybok the response is assigned through scrapy. I don't have access to that really

Comment: @nafas that might be a missing `User-Agent` header. Are you setting it?

Comment: @alecxe well I've tried it with many different agents, the thing is it works for most of the pages(from same domain) but for some like example above doesn't work.

Comment: @nafas I mean that they can be checking your User-Agent header for matching a real browser.

Comment: @alecxe [http://techpatterns.com/downloads/firefox/useragent_switcher_agents.txt](http://techpatterns.com/downloads/firefox/useragent_switcher_agents.txt) I'm using this source to get my USER_AGENTS, the thing I don't understand is why it works for some of the urls but not others

Comment: It could be that you are making too many requests in a short amount of time, and the server doesn't like it. Try setting the `DOWNLOAD_DELAY` to something like `0.25`, or use the [AutoThrottle extension](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/autothrottle.html) to see what happens.